# WPF: Keep background in Border

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a treeview with items that can be colored differently. Like this

[image: border problem]

As you can see the background is bigger than the border. How can I keep the background color inside the border?

This is the relevant code:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:MyClass}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            BorderThickness="1" 
            Margin="2" >                
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                   Foreground="Black" 
                   Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=MyTreeView, Mode=OneWay}" 
                   Background="{Binding Background}" 
                   Margin="3" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Where is the background coming from?

Comment: From `Background="{Binding Background}"` of the `TextBlock`

Comment: My WPF is rusty but it looks like you made the textblock explicitly as wide as the tree view. That is too wide. The best fix would be to use a less rigid way of layouting. Otherwise, maybe you can get the border to clip it's contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the background I use a property in my TextBlock

```
Background="{Binding Background}"
```

In my ViewModel I set the background of the `TreeViewItem` like this

```
var item = new TreeViewItem { Header = myClassInstance };
item.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

which led to the problematic overlapping background color.

I changed it to set the background not to the `TreeViewItem` but to my class instance in the item. So I changed the above 2 lines to

```
var item = new TreeViewItem { Header = myClassInstance };
myClassInstance.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

and it works as expected.